# Issue converting numeric vector to Categorical Factor

Tags: r, vector, factors

I have two integer vectors of *test scores* for males and females, shown below:

```
females =c(57,59,78,79,60,65,68,71,75,48,51,55,56,41,43,44,75,78,80,81,83,83,85)

males=c(48,49,49,30,31,32,35,37,41,86,42,51,53,56,42,44,50,51,65,67,51,56,58,64,64,75)
```

I had to store these together in a new vector called `scores`, shown below:

```
scores = c(females, males)
```

Now I am asked to "create a factor designating the gender of each of the observations in the score vector (*F=female, M=Male*)." This factor is to be stored in a new variable called `gender`.

The problem I've been having and have been passionately googling is if there is even a simple way to assign levels to different parts of an un-unqiue numeric vector.

It seems that to create two levels of `Male` and `Female` with the scores vector is not possible , because there are some "scores" (i.e. 44, 51 etc.) that appear in both my initial `Male` and `Female` vectors, so when combined into the scores vector, there would be no way for R to assign levels in this way.

I've tried stuff like below:

```
gender = factor(c(scores[1:23], scores[24:49]), levels = c("F = Female", "M=Male")
```

The idea was to say that the first 23 values of the score vector should be designated female, and the 24th to 49th values should be designated male, but this produced a bunch of NA values...

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Create a character vector first using `rep()` and then convert that to a factor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response - I'm a little confused how this would help me? From what I understand rep() just replicates the specified values a set number of times..?

Comment: AH yes thank you so much